# Is there liability for late delivery

Tags: halacha, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, transactions, contemporary-halacha, torts-damages

According to halacha, if somebody orders something and the company which delivers it promises it by a certain deadline, is there financial liability if they deliver past that deadline? Assuming of course it still gets delivered in the end?

Comment: Presumably it depends on the contract.

Comment: What kind of financial liability would there be? Was there any loss incurred? Was it direct or grama?